# How to give a password to a zip file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords, zip

How can I give a password to a zip file on Mac OS X without downloading any additional program?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/07/set-zip-password-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 90):

I found the solution.

Go to Terminal and type

> zip -er (zipfile's name).zip (File path)
>
> Enter password: (your password)
>
> Verify password: (type it again)

press enter. That's it. It will be saved to your main folder. You have a passworded zip file now.

Comment: To zip a folder, use above format, to zip a file `zip -e [archive] [file]` **eg: zip -e ~/Desktop/zippedFile.zip/ ~/Documents/FileToZip.doc**

Comment: Note that the recommended flag -e encrypts the file with week encryption that can be broken with brute force. You should use -P instead. P flag uses AES256 encryption that has no known ways to be brute forced when used with sufficiently complex password.

Comment: @djabi Just out of curiosity, where does it really authoritatively say or show that `-e` uses weak encryption and `-P` doesn't? I can't seem to find good info about the type of encryption that these options apply. Moreover, what would happen if both (`-e -P`) were used?

Comment: Not sure -P does what @djabi thinks it does. From the man file on macOS Mojave: _"Use password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any). THIS IS INSECURE! Many  multi-user  operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even  on stand-alone  systems  there  is  always  the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking..."_ Looks to me as though -P is just a way to specify the password on the command line.

Comment: I agree the encryption is weak and "-P" does not change that. From the [zip FAQ](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#crypto): _Finally, note that the original encryption scheme used in all versions of Zip (as well as PKWARE's older products) is quite weak; see "A Known-Plaintext Attack on the PKZIP Stream Cipher" (also as gzip'd PostScript) by Eli Biham and Paul C. Kocher. Recent versions of PKZIP and WinZip include stronger AES encryption, and PGP/GnuPG have provided strong encryption for many years._

Answer (score 17):

Add password for an existing zip file:

```
zipcloak file.zip
```

Limitations listed in [`man zipcloak`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipcloak) for v3.0:

- **zipcloak uses original zip encryption which is considered weak.**
- Large files (> 2 GB) and large archives not yet supported.